# Widget Onclick is not working

Tags: java, android, xml, android-widget

I am trying to create an app which updates every half an hour. and presently trying to launch on more activity on widget click, but its not working

following is my provider.java class

```
public class Provider extends AppWidgetProvider {
public static void updateAppWidget(Context paramContext,
        AppWidgetManager localAppWidgetManager, int i, String string) {

    ComponentName thiswidget = new ComponentName(paramContext,
            Provider.class);

    AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(paramContext);
    int[] allWidgetIds = manager.getAppWidgetIds(thiswidget);

    for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {

        Intent in = new Intent(paramContext, display_widget.class);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                paramContext, 0, in, 0);

        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(
                paramContext.getPackageName(), R.layout.main);

        remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.Main, pendingIntent);
        localAppWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);

    }

}

public void onUpdate(Context paramContext,
        AppWidgetManager paramAppWidgetManager, int[] paramArrayOfInt) {
    int i = paramArrayOfInt.length;

    for (int j = 0;; j++) {
        if (j >= i) {
            return;
        }
        int k = paramArrayOfInt[j];

        updateAppWidget(paramContext, paramAppWidgetManager, k,
                "soome string");
    }
}
```

}

thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: use `PendingIntent.getActivity(paramContext, 0, in, 0);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(paramContext, display_widget.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_BUTTON);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(paramContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button, pendingIntent);
```